# Do Buddhists claim that if there was a self it could not be annihilated?

Tags: self

Do Buddhists claim that if there was a self it could not be annihilated? I dimly remember reading this, but no argument or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

The first and perhaps most famous sutta like that which comes to mind is the *Anatta-lakkhana Sutta: The Discourse on the Not-self Characteristic* (SN22.59) translated [here](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.59/en/sujato) and [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.nymo.html).

I think that says that if something (e.g. form or consciousness or feeling or perception) is impermanent, then it's "not fit" to be regarded as "self".

The word translated as "not fit" is [kalla](https://suttacentral.net/define/kalla) ("clever", "healthy", etc.).

Comment: great answer, thanks. took me a moment to get it!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by ChrisW, the following sutta quotes provide further perspective on the same topic.

From [SN 22.93](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.93/en/bodhi):

> At Savatthi. “Bhikkhus, suppose there was a mountain river sweeping
> downwards, flowing into the distance with a swift current. If on
> either bank of the river kasa grass or kusa grass were to grow, it
> would overhang it; if rushes, reeds, or trees were to grow, they would
> overhang it. If a man being carried along by the current should grasp
> the kasa grass, it would break off and he would thereby meet with
> calamity and disaster; if he should grasp the kusa grass, it would
> break off and he would thereby meet with calamity and disaster; if he
> should grasp the rushes, reeds, or trees, they would break off and he
> would thereby meet with calamity and disaster.
>
> “So too, bhikkhus, the uninstructed worldling … regards form as self,
> or self as possessing form, or form as in self, or self as in form.
> That form of his disintegrates and he thereby meets with calamity and
> disaster. He regards feeling as self … perception as self … volitional
> formations as self … consciousness as self, or self as possessing
> consciousness, or consciousness as in self, or self as in
> consciousness. That consciousness of his disintegrates and he thereby
> meets with calamity and disaster.
>
> “What do you think, bhikkhus, is form permanent or
> impermanent?”—“Impermanent, venerable sir.”…—“Therefore … Seeing thus
> … He understands: ‘… there is no more for this state of being.’”

From [MN 22](https://suttacentral.net/mn22/en/bodhi):

> “Venerable sir, can there be agitation about what is non-existent
> internally?”
>
> “There can be, bhikkhu,” the Blessed One said. “Here, bhikkhu, someone
> has the view: ‘That which is the self is the world; after death I
> shall be permanent, everlasting, eternal, not subject to change; I
> shall endure as long as eternity.’ He hears the Tathāgata or a
> disciple of the Tathāgata teaching the Dhamma for the elimination of
> all standpoints, decisions, obsessions, adherences, and underlying
> tendencies, for the stilling of all formations, for the relinquishing
> of all attachments, for the destruction of craving, for dispassion,
> for cessation, for Nibbāna. He thinks thus: ‘So I shall be
> annihilated! So I shall perish! So I shall be no more!’ Then he
> sorrows, grieves, and laments, he weeps beating his breast and becomes
> distraught. That is how there is agitation about what is non-existent
> internally.”
>
> “Venerable sir, can there be no agitation about what is non-existent
> internally?”
>
> “There can be, bhikkhu,” the Blessed One said. “Here, bhikkhu, someone
> does not have the view: ‘That which is the self is the world…I shall
> endure as long as eternity.’ He hears the Tathāgata or a disciple of
> the Tathāgata teaching the Dhamma for the elimination of all
> standpoints, decisions, obsessions, adherences, and underlying
> tendencies, for the stilling of all formations, for the relinquishing
> of all attachments, for the destruction of craving, for dispassion,
> for cessation, for Nibbāna. He does not think thus: ‘So I shall be
> annihilated! So I shall perish! So I shall be no more!’ Then he does
> not sorrow, grieve, and lament, he does not weep beating his breast
> and become distraught. That is how there is no agitation about what is
> non-existent internally.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are remembering:

[The Fruits of the Ascetic Life](https://suttacentral.net/dn2/en/sujato)

> 3.3. The Doctrine of Ajita Kesakambala One time, sir, I approached Ajita Kesakambala and exchanged greetings with him. When the greetings
> and polite conversation were over, I sat down to one side, and asked
> him the same question.
>
> He said: ‘Great king, there is no meaning in giving, sacrifice, or
> offerings. There’s no fruit or result of good and bad deeds. There’s
> no afterlife. There’s no obligation to mother and father. No beings
> are reborn spontaneously. And there’s no ascetic or brahmin who is
> well attained and practiced, and who describes the afterlife after
> realizing it with their own insight. This person is made up of the
> four primary elements. When they die, the earth in their body merges
> and coalesces with the main mass of earth. The water in their body
> merges and coalesces with the main mass of water. The fire in their
> body merges and coalesces with the main mass of fire. The air in their
> body merges and coalesces with the main mass of air. The faculties are
> transferred to space. Four men with a bier carry away the corpse.
> Their footprints show the way to the cemetery. The bones become
> bleached. Offerings dedicated to the gods end in ashes. Giving is a
> doctrine of morons. When anyone affirms a positive teaching it’s just
> hollow, false nonsense. Both the foolish and the astute are
> annihilated and destroyed when their body breaks up, and don’t exist
> after death.’
>
> And so, when I asked Ajita Kesakambala about the fruits of the ascetic
> life apparent in the present life, he answered with the doctrine of
> annihilationism. It was like someone who, when asked about a mango,
> answered with a breadfruit, or when asked about a breadfruit, answered
> with a mango. I thought: ‘How could one such as I presume to rebuke an
> ascetic or brahmin living in my realm?’ So I neither approved nor
> dismissed that statement of Ajita Kesakambala. I was displeased, but
> did not express my displeasure. Neither accepting what he said nor
> contradicting it, I got up from my seat and left.

Answer (score 0):

A sutta possibly providing an answer is the 2nd and most important sermon of the Buddha, namely, the [Anatta-Lakkhana Sutta: The Discourse on the Not-self Characteristic](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html). Relevant paragraphs for consideration are:

> "...if form were self, then form would not
> lead to affliction ([ābādhāya](https://suttacentral.net/define/%C4%81b%C4%81dha)) and it should obtain regarding form: 'May my form
> be thus, may my form not be thus'; and indeed, O monks, since form is
> not-self, therefore form leads to affliction and it does not obtain
> regarding form: 'May my form be thus, may my form not be thus.'
>
> "... if feeling were self, then feeling
> would not lead to affliction and it should obtain regarding feeling:
> 'May my feeling be thus, may my feeling not be thus'; and indeed, O
> monks, since feeling is not-self, therefore feeling leads to
> affliction and it does not obtain regarding feeling: 'May my feeling
> be thus, may my feeling not be thus.'
>
> "... if perception were self, then
> perception would not lead to affliction and it should obtain regarding
> perception: 'May my perception be thus, may my perception not be
> thus'; and indeed, O monks, since perception is not-self, therefore,
> perception leads to affliction and it does not obtain regarding
> perception: 'May my perception be thus, may my perception not be
> thus.'
>
> "... if mental formations were
> self, then mental formations would not lead to affliction and it
> should obtain regarding mental formations: 'May my perception be thus,
> may my mental formations not be thus'; and indeed, O monks, since
> mental formations are not-self, therefore, mental formations lead to
> affliction and it does not obtain regarding mental formations: 'May my
> mental formations be thus, may my mental formations not be thus.'
>
> "... if consciousness were self, then
> consciousness would not lead to affliction and it should obtain
> regarding consciousness: 'May my consciousness be thus, may my
> consciousness not be thus'; and indeed, O monks, since consciousness
> is not-self, therefore, consciousness leads to affliction and it does
> not obtain regarding consciousness: 'May my consciousness be thus, may
> my consciousness not be thus.'

While the above is referring to [ābādhāya](https://suttacentral.net/define/%C4%81b%C4%81dha) (sickness), it is indirectly saying, if there was a self, such a self should be permanent or not capable of sickness (and thus decay and death).

Answer (score -1):

No, they don't.

Those who claim a 'self' defined what they mean by the 'self' and some thinker at the time of Buddha, for example, the Sankhya philosophers posit a self that can not be annihilated and the Buddist show that it is not true.

It's like if group A says a unicorn exists. The Buddhist didn't say 'for a unicorn to exist it has to have a single horn on its head' it's not the business of the Buddist defining what that other group thinks, it's group A who claims to know a horse with a single spiral horn on its head.

So in short when the Buddhists say 'not-self...not-self' they are not predicting the existence of a thing called self.

If you ask them what is self they will probably say an idea by some stupid people, but they won't define it for you.